# PHPmailer + gmail

Tags: php, phpmailer, gmail

Estou usando a última versão do PHPMailer para disparar e-mail usando minha conta do Gmail, essa aplicação roda localmente, abaixo meu código (copiado do próprio GitHub do PHPMailer falando sobre envio ao Gmail):

```
$mail = new PHPMailer;
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
$mail->Host = 'smtp.gmail.com';
$mail->Port = 587;
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = "xx@gmail.com";
$mail->Password = "xx";
$mail->setFrom('xx@gmail.com', 'First Last');
$mail->addAddress('xx@xx.com.br', 'John Doe');
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer GMail SMTP test';
$mail->Body = 'This is a plain-text message body';
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo "Message sent!";
}
```

Mas da erro, esse aqui:

```
2018-06-29 20:15:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 smtp.gmail.com ESMTP d18-v6sm6204628qtl.32 - gsmtp
2018-06-29 20:15:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: EHLO localhost
2018-06-29 20:15:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 250-smtp.gmail.com at your service, [189.120.238.241]250-SIZE 35882577250-8BITMIME250-STARTTLS250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES250-PIPELINING250 SMTPUTF8
2018-06-29 20:15:09 CLIENT -> SERVER: STARTTLS
2018-06-29 20:15:09 SERVER -> CLIENT: 220 2.0.0 Ready to start TLS
SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
2018-06-29 20:15:10 CLIENT -> SERVER: QUIT
2018-06-29 20:15:10 SERVER -> CLIENT: 
2018-06-29 20:15:10 SMTP ERROR: QUIT command failed: 
SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
Mailer Error: SMTP connect() failed. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Troubleshooting
```

O que mais posso tentar?

PS: permitir aplicativos menos seguros já está marcado como ATIVADO no Gmail

Comment: Lembrando que não precisa habilitar aplicativos menos seguros, o PHPMailer já suporta XOAuth2 faz um certo tempo (desde o 5.2.11). Usando esse fluxo, o proprietário da conta autoriza sua aplicação, que aparece na lista de aplicativos conectados na conta dele. https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer/wiki/Using-Gmail-with-XOAUTH2

Answer (score 1):

A mensagem de erro principal é esta:

> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.

Isto pode ocorrer por vários motivos:

- A rede do teu servidor/hospedagem esta bloqueando o acesso ao smtp.gmail.com
- Algum firewall ou proxy estão impedindo de se comunicar com o smtp.gmail.com
- Algum proxy esta impedindo da sua rede (se o teste for local) usar conexões seguras

No entanto o mais provavel problema é que a tua hospedagem ou PHP local não esteja com a extensão de SSL ativada, ou seja os PHP só irão conseguir se comunicar com conexões não seguras, para corrigir esse problema vá no `php.ini` e descomente essa linha (se for PHP 5 e 7.1):

Windows (e windows server):

```
;extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Deixando assim:

```
extension=php_openssl.dll
```

Linux:

```
;extension=openssl.so
```

Deixando assim:

```
extension=openssl.so
```

Se for **php 7.2**, tanto linux quanto windows quanto Mac a linha estara apenas assim:

```
;extension=openssl
```

Descomente assim:

```
extension=openssl
```

Então salve o documento e reinicie o Apache (ou LightTTPD ou Nginx) e o FastCGI (se o teu servidor usar isto, geralmente reinicia sozinho, mas depende de como configurou).

Então crie um arquivo chamado `phpinfo.php` e coloque isto:

```
<?php
var_dump(extension_loaded('openssl'));
```

Então observe se apareceu isto:

> ```
> bool(true)
> ```

Se aparecer:

> ```
> bool(false)
> ```

É porque você esqueceu algo, ou editou o `php.ini` errado (alguns servidores tem mais de um para coisas diferentes).

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, vamos lá, aqui da bool(true); (ou seja, está tudo certo). Estou testando localmente, sem nenhum tipo de firewall na minha máquina, mas o erro continua o mesmo, com qualquer conta do Gmail.... onde será que está o erro?

Comment: @caiocafardo você ativou ou não a extensão de openssl?

Comment: Sim, está ativa!

Comment: @caiocafardo criar um arquivo php vazio chamado teste.php e coloca isso nele `<?php fsockopen("tls://smtp.gmail.com", 587, $errno, $errstr, 30); var_dump($errno, $errstr);` e me diga o que retorna.